# This in arrow function by using addEventListener. How to remove listener?

Tags: javascript

I have a simple peice of code where I want to add and remove an event listener. Here everithing works perfectly. The context of `this` is `divideBtn`.

```
const divideBtn = document.querySelector('.button--div');

function fu() {
    console.log('click');
    console.log(this);
};

window.onresize = function () {
    let windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
    if ((windowWidth >= 992)) {
        divideBtn.addEventListener('click', fu)
    };
    if ((windowWidth < 992)) {
        divideBtn.removeEventListener('click', fu)

    };
};
```

The problem is when I'm using an arrow function, the value of `this` has been changed and now is `window`. How can I add and remove my event listener from `divideBtn` when using arrow functions (I think closures might help)?

```
const divideBtn = document.querySelector('.button--div');

function fu() {
    console.log('click');
    console.log(this);
};

window.onresize = function () {
    let windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
    if ((windowWidth >= 992)) {
        divideBtn.addEventListener('click', () => fu())
    };
    if ((windowWidth < 992)) {
        divideBtn.removeEventListener('click', () => fu())

    };
};
```

I know what the problem is but I can't work out how to remove the event listener after changing it to use an arrow function.

Comment: Why do you want to use an arrow function in the first place? Why not stick with your first code block?

Comment: Hi, I wanted ('click', () => fu(value). I have already solved the problem. Thanks for note.

Comment: I see. You should share how you solved the problem by adding an answer if the current answers don't (this is so that future readers will benefit).

Comment: I removed arrow function and used the same name of function: divideBtn.addEventListener('click',  fu) in both cases.

Comment: If you used that approach then how did you pass `value` into the `fu` functions like you were with the arrow function approach?

Comment: In this way it is not possible. I skipped to use value into the fu. Thanks for you Feedbacks Nick.

Answer (score 3):

**addeventListener** and **removeEventListener** must get the same function. When you pass a callback like that

```
() => something()
```

Every time js creates a new function. It means that in your case you provide different functions to **addeventListener** and **removeEventListener**

To solve the problem, use it like that.

```
const divideBtn = document.querySelector('.button--div');
const fu = () => {
    console.log('click');
    console.log(this);
};

window.onresize = function () {
    let windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
    if ((windowWidth >= 992)) {
        divideBtn.addEventListener('click', fu)
    };
    if ((windowWidth < 992)) {
        divideBtn.removeEventListener('click', fu)

    };
};
```

Comment: this code is slow and causes jank; `.innerWidth` is a slow property, and `resize` fires dozens, maybe 100s of times a second. debounce the event to a few dozen ms before accessing the innerWidth property.